# how to convert nested loop to 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

i would ask if there is some way to print some thing called (Star pattern)!

```
for(int x=1; x<=5; x++)
{
    for(int y=1; y<=x; y++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

the output (i guess...)

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

so...
could you tell me please, it is possible to print same with array 2d?
thank you for help!

Comment: What do you mean by "print same with array 2d"?

Comment: BackSlash i mean same pattern with multi dimensional array!?

Comment: you want to create a dynamic 2d array with the size at the number of stars in the row?  can you share a sample output?

Comment: The output of your code will differ from what you have written. The first line will contain one star and the number of stars will grow from line to line.

Comment: segFaulter  yes..! , i don't know so much about arrays! (Especially multi dimensional array), just want to print this star pattern above with multi dimensional array (IF ITS POSSIBLE)

Comment: m.vokhm  yes , you are right (sorry!and i apology to you friend , i'm using google translate to speak with you)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: it's possible. You have to crate an array of 5x5 and fill previously with stars and spaces. Then you have to create a function to print that array.

Comment: thank you =)  i think i understand , but  the hard part for me... i haven't any idea how to create the function, its so complicate ! i just started learning multi dimensional array

Comment: `You have to crate an array of 5x5` - Not necessarily. You can create a 2d array with dynamic row size (`int[5]` for the first row, `int[1]` for the last row).

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean creating and handling arrays that consist of arrays of different sizes? Then it might look, for example, like the following:

```
public class TestArray {

    public static void main(String... args) {
    // Create and fill the array we need    
        char[][] array = new char[5][];          // Create an array of 5 arrays
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {    
            array[i] = new char[i+1];            // Each item of the array is a new array of a new size 
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
                array[i][j] = '*';               // fill the new array with stars
        }

    // Print the contents of the array
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {        
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) // Each item is an array  
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);        // print its contents
            System.out.println();                     // new line       
        }

    }
```

Comment: oh thank you =) yes i want this exactly, but still i have to study at this to understand how it work (lol)